# Eloquent Relationship Controller throw to Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-one, eloquent

I have two table ( student and phone) with one-to-one relationships. The problem is the StudentController throws to *Trying to get property of non-object*

Here is my code

**Phone.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
//
protected $table = 'phone';

protected $primaryKey = 'student_id';

protected $fillable = [
    'student_id',
    'phone_number',
];

public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'id_student');
}
}
```

**Student.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;




class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'student';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nisn',
        'student_name',
        'date_birth',
        'sex',
    ];

    protected $dates = ['date_birth'];


    public function getStudentNameAttribute($student_name)
    {
        return ucwords($student_name);
    }


    public function setStudentNameAttribute($student_name)
    {

        $this->attributes['student_name'] = strtolower($student_name);
        //return strtolower($student_name);
    }


    public function phone() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'student_id');
    }      

    }
```

**Phone Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTablePhone extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('phone', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {          
            $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->primary('student_id');
            $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();

                $table->foreign('student_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('student')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('phone');
    }
}
```

**StudentController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $input = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'nisn' => 'required|string|size:4|unique:student,nisn',
        'student_name' => 'required|string|max:30',
        'date_birth' => 'required|date',
        'sex' => 'required|in:M,W',
        'phone_number' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:phone,phone_number',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('student/create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    Student::create($input);


    $phone = new Phone;
    $phone->phone_number = $request->input('phone_number');
    $student->phone()->save($phone);

    return redirect('student');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    $student->phone_number = $student->phone->phone_number;
    return view('student.edit', compact('student'));
}
```

the errors appears when i access the "student/edit" says there is ErrorException (E_NOTICE) `$student->phone_number = $student->phone->phone_number;`

and when i create store data form on "student/create"
`"Undefined variable: student"`$student->phone()->save($phone);`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your Student class is named `Siswa` but in the relationship you used `Student`.

Comment: Hi @Camilo thanks, sorry i forgot to to edit, but the errors still the same

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)  Trying to get property of non-object thats all i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `store` method you never defined a variable named `student`. There is no `$student = ...`  or a variable being passed to that method named `student`. Nothing magically gets created in scope for you.

You are trying to use a variable that doesn't exist as an object `$student->...`, you never defined `$student`.

In the `edit` method you have:

```
$student = Student::findOrFail($id);
$student->phone_number = $student->phone->phone_number;
```

`$student->phone` could be `null`. You will have to check for `null` here. A Single realtionship type will return a Model instance or `null`.

`(null)->anything` "Trying to get a property of a non-object"

**Update:**

Im not sure what you want examples of but:

```
$student = Student::create(....);
```

Now you have a variale named `student` defined and it will be the object you expect, based on the context of your code.

```
if ($student->phone) {
    $student->phone_number = $student->phone->phone_number;
}
```

Check if `$student->phone` has a "truthy" value (objects return `true` when cast to `bool`, a `null` would be `false`), if we have the relationship we will pull the `phone_number` from it.

I am unsure why you are adding that phone number in that way but you have the option of creating an 'accessor' on the model for that attribute:

```
public function getPhoneNumberAttribute()
{
    return $this->phone ? $this->phone->phone_number : null;
    // php 7+
    return $this->phone->phone_number ?? null;
}
```

That type of thing, now  `$student->phone_number` will get that value from the relationship for you ... that method could be tweaked but basically that is it.

Comment: thank you so much for the complete explaination, if you dont mind i have one more question, how to cheking `null` on the update? here is my code ```$phone->phone_number = $request->input('phone_number');``` it throw me **Creating default object from empty value**

Comment: same kind of issue, you did not define a variable named `phone` ... you have to define a variable to use it like an object ... `$anythingThatIsNotDefined->blah = 'blah';` -> `Creating default object from empty value` ... it knows you want to set a property on an object, but you have no object, so it creates an object and assigns that property for you  (creating default object [stdClass] from empty value [undefined variable])